# Use Latex in Matlab legend?

Tags: matlab, latex, legend

My matlab does not accept my latex . For example if I use `legend('b^{+6}\rightarrow b^{+7}')`, it does not show me the arrow, How I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Try with Latex interpreter, something like

```
legend({'$b^{+6}\rightarrow b^{+7}$'}, 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

---

Tested under R2012a:

[image]

Comment: @user3271929 What Matlab version? And do you have Latex interpreter installed on your PC?

Comment: Student version  R2013a

Comment: How I can install latex  interpreter in my linux?

Comment: @user3271929 Try to restart Matlab and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to set the latex interpreter after the legend command:

```
l = legend({'$b^{+6}\rightarrow b^{+7}$'})
set(l, 'Interpreter', 'Latex');
```

This worked in Matlab R2016b

Answer (score 1):

For `xlabel` and `ylabel`, simply use something like:

```
xlabel( ' $\Delta t$ [ sec ] ','Interpreter','latex')
```

For some reason, Matlab has more difficulty with legends; you have to set the interpreter *after* the legend has been created:

```
legend_handle = legend('$b^{+6}\rightarrow b^{+7}$');
set(legend_handle,'Interpreter','latex')
```

Answer (score 1):

if the comand...
l = legend({'$b^{+6}\rightarrow b^{+7}$'})
set(l, 'Interpreter', 'Latex');
dosn't work. Try to put "hold on" after the "set" instruction".